# What cheap PCI modems can be used to open two serial ports at the same time?

Tags: windows-xp, modem, pci

I have three PCI fax modems:

- [USR 56K PCI Faxmodem](http://www.usr.com/products/modem/modem-oem.asp)
- [Hiro 56K V.92 Data PCI Fax Modem](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=402917)
- [Conexant PCI Faxmodem](http://www.conexant.com/products/entry.jsp?id=105)

With any combination of of these modems ( two USR, one USR one Hiro ) Windows XP only allows me to open one modem at a time.

Any suggestions of two PCI modem's that I could open at the same time?

Comment: Have you tried running two copies of hyper terminal at the same time?

Comment: Yes that's the problem.

Comment: you probably need a better terminal program...

Answer (score 1):

Just a stab in the dark..could it be IRQ's...I have not had to deal with them in so long that I don't remember when they went out of style..but if they are on the same IRQ then maybe that is the conflict..

Comment: Yep, you can check the COM port interrupt address in the BIOS, and usually change it too. It'll need to be different for each COM port you want to address.

Comment: @Chris Thorpe: not in the BIOS, since all of these are likely Winmodems; you'd need to do this in the Modems control panel or in the Device Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Just run Hyperterm twice as follows:

Start -> Run -> hypertrm
Start -> Run -> hypertrm

Do it twice, and you get two copies of it running at once.